# Count how many values occur consecutively by factor

Tags: r, count

I am trying to count the number of times a value occurs consecutively for a given variable.  I would like to store these values in another variable.  It is similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012516/count-how-many-consecutive-values-are-true) but I would like to perform it for each factor--there are over 75,000 different factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer I used:  I wanted to count the number of strings of ones and zeros and used the following code.

```
out.full <- within(df, {
smaller <- unlist(lapply(split(var1, var2), function(x) sequence(rle(x)$lengths)))
cum.ones <- replace(smaller, var1 == 1,NA)
cum.zeroes <- replace(smaller, var1 == 0, NA)
rm(smaller)
})
```