# How to count cumulative non-zero variables in a very large data frame without for loop in R?

Tags: r

I have a huge df and trying to execute follow code takes too long. Anyway to speed it up?

```
df$col2 <- 0
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
    if (df$col1 > 0) {
        df$col2[i] <- df$col2[i-1] + 1
    }
    else {
        df$col2[i] <- 0
    }
}
```

*Example data*

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 0, 10, 28, 0, 0, 2))
```

*Expected result*

```
col1 col2
   1    1
   0    0
  10    1
  28    2
   0    0
   0    0
   2    1
```

I am trying to use `col2` to count cumulative non-zero variables in `col1` and reset the count when I hit a `0` in `col1`.

Comment: You say you have a huge dataframe. How many rows and columns?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses the `rleid()` function from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(col1, col2 = cumsum(col1 != 0)), by = rleid(col1 != 0)][, rleid := NULL][]
#   col1 col2
#1:    1    1
#2:    0    0
#3:   10    1
#4:   28    2
#5:    0    0
#6:    0    0
#7:    2    1
```

The `rleid()` function is *a convenience function for generating a run-length type id column to be used in grouping operations* (`?rleid`). It is applied to the sequence of logical values created by `col1 != 0` which distinghuishes zero and non-zero values. Within each group, `cumsum()` is used to count the non-zero values. Finally, the `rleid`column is removed from the result.

As alternative, `cumsum()` could be replaced by a simple sequence.

```
setDT(df)[, .(col1, col2 = seq_len(.N)), by = rleid(col1 != 0)][col1 == 0, col2 := 0][
  , rleid := NULL][]
```

However, this also counts subsequent zero values which wasn't requested. So, these counts in `col2` have to be reset to zero for all rows where `col1` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'll annotate what I think are the errors and show what I *think* would be a faster equivalent:

```
df$col2 <- 0
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) { 
    if (df$col1 > 0) {   # at least a "semantic" error
        df$col2[i] <- df$col2[i-1] + 1}
    else { df$col2[i] <- 0 }
}
```

Asking for `if (df$col1 > 0)` will be comparing a vector to a single value without indexing which of the multiple values should be tested. Hence, calling it a "semantic error" because R will only test the first value of df$col1 in each pass through the loop. I'm guessing you want something along these lines:

```
df$col2 <- cumsum( c(0, head(df$col1, -1) > 0 ) )
df$col2[ c(TRUE, head(df$col1 == 0)]  <- 0
```

That will construct the running count you asked for and then zero out the entries where the was no increment.

Comment: Thank you for point out the semantic error. What I meant to type was df$col1[i] >0

Comment: @42- It seems there's a typo in your second line. (and the OP has clarified his question)

Comment: @42- It seems the running count is not reset when a zero is hit in `col1` as the OP had requested in his clarifying comment.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fast (but tricky) solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012516/count-how-many-consecutive-values-are-true/#5019695).

So in your case:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 0, 10, 28, 0, 0, 2))

f7 <- function(x) { tmp <- cumsum(x) ; tmp - cummax((!x)*tmp) }

df$col2 <- f7(df$col1 > 0)

df
#   col1 col2
# 1    1    1
# 2    0    0
# 3   10    1
# 4   28    2
# 5    0    0
# 6    0    0
# 7    2    1
```

Comment: Thank. This helps a lot.